# 'longtable' caption without incrementing 'table'?

Tags: numbering, captions, longtable

For reasons both complex and confusing, I would like to caption a `longtable` **without** incrementing the `table` counter in the process.

I want to have two consecutive `longtable` environments to be captioned with identical table numbers; i.e. one `longtable` captioned "Table x.y: Data Set (Part A)" and one captioned "Table x.y: Data Set (Part B)", with x.y being identical for both tables.

Apparently however, even `\caption*{}` command bumps `table`. I am a bit at a loss here.

**Note:** *I know* that the `xtab` package would enable me to have *one* long table with switches of headers and captions mid-table. However I got a (different) problem with that package, akin to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15876) but sadly not solved by egreg's answer there; so this question should be considered `longtable`-only as `xtab`, `supertabular` etc. don't float my boat right now. :-(

Comment: not an option to manually decrease the counter at the end of the table?

Comment: @whlt3: \facepalm... sometimes I think too difficult, especially when I'm not really comfortable with the environment. I only thought about suppressing the increment, not about the manual decrement... `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` is all that's needed...

Comment: I've added it as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Longtable caption numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33395/longtable-caption-numbering)

Comment: @rriemann: More like the other way around, hm? ;-)

Comment: Whatever is more helpful to the reader… :) I think the answers are better for the other question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using the numbered `longtable` environment, use the unnumbered `longtable*` environment; enable with `\usepackage{caption}`.

See [Axel Sommerfeldt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2574/axel-sommerfeldt)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33414) to [Longtable caption numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33395/longtable-caption-numbering)
.

Answer (score 17):

You can simply decrease the table counter after the first table, this will ensure the second table receives the same number. Simply put

```
\addtocounter{table}{-1}
```

In between the two tables you wish to show.

Comment: It is a bit wierd how LaTeX sometimes forces you to do something, then take it back again. I still have problems wrapping my mind around it, being so intent on not doing the thing in the first place I lose sight of the end to justify the means.

Comment: The answer provided by Joel Purra is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 4):

A patch for `longtable`:

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifLT@nocaption
\preto\longtable{\LT@nocaptiontrue}
\appto\endlongtable{%
  \ifLT@nocaption
    \addtocounter{table}{\m@ne}%
  \fi}
\preto\LT@caption{%
  \noalign{\global\LT@nocaptionfalse}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: @david-carlisle
Is there any reason that the longtable package always increment the table counter, by default?