# Longtable caption numbering

Tags: tables, numbering, captions, longtable

I am trying to prevent a table from showing up in the list of tables. I used long table to create the table. This is the first table in my document. I know the `\caption*{}` command should do the trick but something weird is happening. Although the table doesn't show up in the list of tables but when I insert the next table it has a caption of "Table 2: ****". I want the numbering to start with 1 rather than 2. Can someone help?

```
    \documentclass[12 pt]{article}
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{caption}

    \begin{document}
     First table is inserted here (longtable).
    \begin{longtable}{l l}
    \hline
        A & A1 \\
        B & B1 \\   
    \hline
    \caption*{}\label{TableNomen}
    \end{longtable}

    \newpage
    Second table inserted here.
    \begin{table} 
    \centering
    \caption{Influence of X}\label{TableC}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
\hline 
    $10^{-5}$ & $80\times40$ & 16 & 10 \\
    $10^{-4}$ & $80\times40$ & 21 & 11 \\       
\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \newpage
    \listoftables 
    \end{document}
```

**Page 1**

[image]

**Page 2**

[image]

**List of tables**

[image]

Comment: @Bavarious: One needs 15 reputation to flag a post. (I did it for John, though.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Instead of posting code snippets, it is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: I am having what I think is a similar issue here:

[Multiple List of Tables entry for single longtable][1]


  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34515/multiple-list-of-tables-entry-for-single-threeparttablex-type-table-that-spans

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

```
\addtocounter{table}{-1}
```

inside the `longtable` environment. As Boris said in his answer, if you don't want a caption for the `longtable`, you can safely delete the `\caption*` and `\label` commands. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

 \begin{longtable}{l l}
   A1 & A2
   \addtocounter{table}{-1} 
\end{longtable}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{test table}
  \label{tab:test}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  text1 & text2
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

If the `caption` package is loaded anyway you can use the `longtable*` environment which does not increment the table counter. (See `ltcaption` package documentation for details.)

As opposite to `\addtocounter{table}{-1}` this solution does never make trouble when used with `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
 First table is inserted here (longtable).
\begin{longtable*}{l l}
\hline
    A & A1 \\
    B & B1 \\   
\hline
%\caption*{Some text}
\end{longtable*}

\newpage
Second table inserted here.
\begin{table} 
\centering
\caption{Influence of X}\label{TableC}
...
\end{table}

\newpage
\listoftables 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to have a caption, just omit `\caption*{}` altogether.  By the way, you do not need `\label` either: you do not number your table.

Comment: But this won't solve the problem with the counter.