# Longtable confuses totalcount package

Tags: longtable, totalcount

I'm using a `longtable` for the nomenclature produced by the `nomencl` package. Here, the `longtable` serves as a `tabluar` replacement. Unfortunately, the usage confuses the `totalcount` package resulting in an uncorrect table count.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[figure,table]{totalcount}

\begin{document}
\verb|\totaltables| is \totaltables, but should be 2.

\begin{table}One\caption{Table One}\end{table} % ONE
\begin{table}Two\caption{Table Two}\end{table} % TWO

\begin{longtable}{cc}
Long & Bla
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You are using three tables, so the count is correct. `longtable` does not have a `longtable` counter but uses the standard `table` counter.

Comment: I don't have the `totalcount` package, but you can check [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32553/longtable-caption-without-incrementing-table). Looks like it could help you.

Comment: @TonioElGringo, thanks! That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`longtable` increments the table counter and then arranges that `\caption` does not increment it. (So not like `table` which relies on `\caption` to increment the counter.)

This simplifies some aspects of having multiple captions for continued page heads in longtable, but it's not that brilliant a design really.

Since you know you haven't used `\caption` in this `longtable` you can set the counter back one to make up for `longtable` having incremented it:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[figure,table]{totalcount}

\begin{document}
\verb|\totaltables| is \totaltables, but should be 2.

\begin{table}One\caption{Table One}\end{table} % ONE
\begin{table}Two\caption{Table Two}\end{table} % TWO

\begin{longtable}{cc}
Long & Bla
\end{longtable}
\addtocounter{table}{-1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this appears to be a duplicate, I'll vote to close

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I'm going to use the starred `longtable*` environment of the `caption` as suggested in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33414/3061).