# Why does supertabular put the page break early in all kinds of situations?

Tags: page-breaking, supertabular

In this MWE, `supertabular` breaks the page (or column, if one is using `twocolumn`) early. In fact, the first page holds only 5 lines, while the second holds 7.

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{supertabular}{p{3mm}}
    1\\ 2(  3\\ 4(  5\\
    1\\ 2\\ 3\\ 4\\ 5\\ 6\\ 7\\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I thought his may have something to do with the presence of the parentheses, but I can reproduce a less severe issue (6 lines vs. 7) without them as well:

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}
\begin{supertabular}{p{1.7mm}}
    1   2\\ 3   4\\ 5   6\\
    1\\ 2\\ 3\\ 4\\ 5\\ 6\\ 7\\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In my document, I can even reproduce the issue without any parentheses or line breaks in cells. That is a bit harder to reproduce as an MWE, however.

I have tried the approach described in [Prevent xtab breaking table too soon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15876/prevent-xtab-breaking-table-too-soon) and [Prevent supertabular* from breaking too early](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78822/prevent-supertabular-from-breaking-too-earlym) without success.

**Edit**: Here's another example not involving line breaks in cells, but a line break in the `\tablehead`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\def\heads{Head Head Head Head Head Head }
\edef\mycont{\heads\heads\heads\heads\heads\heads\heads}
\tablehead{\multicolumn{1}{p{\dimexpr \columnwidth - 12pt}}{\mycont}\\}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{supertabular}{p{1cm}}
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's one using `\tablefirsthead` (in this case, it seems the second column is long, rather than the first too short - but they should have the same length anywy, and I don't get a box warning, either):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\tablefirsthead{}
\tablehead{Continued\\}
\begin{document}
\begin{supertabular}{p{1cm}}
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's one using `\tablecaption`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\tablecaption{Caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{supertabular}{p{1cm}}
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit 2:**
I also found [Too large bottom margin with xtab (or supertabular)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269428/too-large-bottom-margin-with-xtab-or-supertabular) and [Long tables (spanning multiple pages), put side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269018/long-tables-spanning-multiple-pages-put-side-by-side) and tried their solutions.

I need `twocolumn`, so `longtable` won't work; and the best solution for the first link is even worse:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage[nofoot]{geometry}
\tablefirsthead{}
\tablehead{H\\}
\begin{document}
\begin{xtabular}{p{1cm}}
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
\end{xtabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I think my summary question is: is this fixable at all, or should I refrain from using `supertabular`/`xtab` if I want my tables to break correctly?

Comment: TeX.SE must be broken. I asked this 9 hours ago, and there's not even a comment. I cannot remember this ever happening.

Comment: `supertabular` decides to issue a page break based on a very disputable heuristic for evaluating the space taken so far. Possibly `xtab` is better, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I got slightly better results by removing the wrong heuristic used by `supertabular` that adds 1pt for every line.

Of course this is not a magic wand that will work in every case.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{showframe}

% https://www.guitex.org/home/forum/5-tex-e-latex/26889-supertabular-e-twocolumn-riempimento-parziale-altezza-testo?lang=it#26893
\makeatletter
\def\mod@estimate@lineht{% 
  \ST@lineht=\arraystretch \baslineskp
  %\global\advance\ST@lineht by 1\p@ 
  \ST@stretchht\ST@lineht\advance\ST@stretchht-\baslineskp
  \ifdim\ST@stretchht<\z@\ST@stretchht\z@\fi
  \ST@trace\tw@{Average line height: \the\ST@lineht}% 
  \ST@trace\tw@{Stretched line height: \the\ST@stretchht}% 
}
\newenvironment{strictsupertabular}
  {\let\estimate@lineht\mod@estimate@lineht\supertabular}
  {\endsupertabular}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tablefirsthead{}
\tablehead{H\\}
\begin{strictsupertabular}{p{1cm}}
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\9\\0\\
\end{strictsupertabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not see any difference between `supertabular` and `strictsupertabular` in this example.

Comment: @bers Don't you? I sure do.

Comment: I really don't. The left column breaks after 34 numbers ending in "4", the right column has 35 numbers ending in "8", in both cases, on TeX Live 2020 on Linux and MiKTeX on Windows.

Comment: @bers That's much better than what you get from `supertabular`, isn't it? You ***can't*** obtain equalized columns automatically with `supertabular`. That's the problem.

Comment: I get the exact same result for `supertabular`.

Comment: (I should have said 44 and 45 in the comment above.)

Comment: I think the confusion may stem from the fact that your picked the final MWE from my post, which is a variant inspired by a related post to show that related solution *do not work*. So the potential improvement in your answer maybe doesn't result from inroducing `supertabular`, but from getting rid of `\usepackage[nofoot]{geometry}` and `xtab`.