# xtab: Prevent table break if no row is printed

Tags: xtab

For this MWE, the table caption and header are printed without any rows from the table body.So, how can I make sure that the table breaks if at least one row is printed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xtab,booktabs,multirow,lipsum,showframe}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]
newline\\
newline\\
newline\\
newline\\
newline\\

\begin{center}
\tablecaption{this is table caption}
\tablefirsthead{\toprule First&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name} \\ \midrule}
%
\tablehead{%
\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{{\bfseries  Continued from previous column}} \\
\toprule
First&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Name}\\ \midrule}
%
\tabletail{\\ \midrule}
\tablelasttail{%
\\\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{r}{{Concluded}} \\ \bottomrule}
\begin{xtabular}{ll}
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text comes\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text comes here too \\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text\\
    content & some text
\end{xtabular}%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you could use the needspace package and put something like `\needspace{5\baselineskip}` before the table

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So do you mean that there is no general fix to this problem?

Comment: isn't that a general fix?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I loaded `needspace` and wrote `\needspace{5\baselineskip}` just before the table and the result is the same when I deleted some dummy line breaks before the table.

Comment: the amount was just a guess looking at the imge: `\Needspace{15\baselineskip}\begin{center}` works

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am afraid I don't understand something. When I put that line before the table, it moved to the next page leaving large white space at the end of the previous page. Is it possible to make this environment float in order to make the trailing text fill this space? Please take a look at the output of this [MWE](https://pastebin.com/3apZPetM) to know what I mean.

Comment: In general that is the only thing you can do if there is not space on the page, floating a multi-page construct is tricky, although you could put the whole thing in `\afterpage` there are probably examples on this site